# Image Display | Banner div & Styling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I’ve create a very simple client banner: 1 row of 6 images and an orange background. I'm not sure what my best options are for removing the seemingly doubled amount of padding that is automatically created between each image. Here’s where you can view the current banner: http://dalaigroup.com/maryland-seo/

What I'm trying to keep in mind, is how the images redistribute for a mobile device. The excess padding and margin space is much more noticeable here. Creating zero or negative margin space doesn't work in my favor, because of how the images reformat for mobile.

I'm not sure if I should be creating containers around every 2 images, working in a responsive table, or writing separate code for a mobile version. Is it necessary to write separate code for a client banner like this? How can I write this so that I have more control over the margin and padding? When I try to set specific sizes for these elements, the logo sizes are easily compromised.

Any tips you have will really help. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Above each of your divs that is holding the image is an empty `<p>` tag. This is causing the extra space on top of each of your images. Removing those, as seen in my edit below, should equalize the spacing.

A few other recommendations on the images:

- Be careful setting exact width on the images in bootstrap, it could cause spacing issues when viewed on a smaller screen.
- Bootstrap has these two classes which you could add to the image that will keep them centered and scale their size proportionately according to user screen size: `<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="foo" />`
- <strike>On the snippet below, vertical margin is missing because it isn't pulling the WordPress CSS from your stylesheet</strike>

Edit: Added the class with margin definitions from the URL you provided

```css
.aligncenter {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row" style="background: #fe8101;">
 <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-16855" title="McCormick" src="http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/McCormick-Logo-Small-Square.png" alt="McCormick-Logo" srcset="http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/McCormick-Logo-Small-Square.png 250w, http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/McCormick-Logo-Small-Square-150x150.png 150w" sizes="(max-width: 250px) 100vw, 250px" height="250" width="250"></div>

 <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-16272" title="Adidas" src="http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Adidas-Logo-Small-Square.jpg" alt="Adidas-Logo" srcset="http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Adidas-Logo-Small-Square.jpg 250w, http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Adidas-Logo-Small-Square-150x150.jpg 150w" sizes="(max-width: 250px) 100vw, 250px" height="250" width="250"></div>

 <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-16271" title="Abercrombie &amp; Fitch" src="http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Abercrombie-and-Fitch-Logo-Small-Square.jpg" alt="Abercrombie-and-Fitch-Logo" srcset="http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Abercrombie-and-Fitch-Logo-Small-Square.jpg 250w, http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Abercrombie-and-Fitch-Logo-Small-Square-150x150.jpg 150w" sizes="(max-width: 250px) 100vw, 250px" height="250" width="250"></div>

 <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-16274" title="Citibank" src="http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Citibank-Logo-Small-Square.jpg" alt="Citibank-Logo" srcset="http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Citibank-Logo-Small-Square.jpg 250w, http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Citibank-Logo-Small-Square-150x150.jpg 150w" sizes="(max-width: 250px) 100vw, 250px" height="250" width="250"></div>

 <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-16288" title="Sheraton Hotels" src="http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Sheraton-Logo-Small-Square.jpg" alt="Sheraton-Hotels-Logo" srcset="http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Sheraton-Logo-Small-Square.jpg 250w, http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Sheraton-Logo-Small-Square-150x150.jpg 150w" sizes="(max-width: 250px) 100vw, 250px" height="250" width="250"></div>

 <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-16278" title="Gap" src="http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Gap-Logo-Small-Square.jpg" alt="Gap-Logo" srcset="http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Gap-Logo-Small-Square.jpg 250w, http://dalaigroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Gap-Logo-Small-Square-150x150.jpg 150w" sizes="(max-width: 250px) 100vw, 250px" height="250" width="250"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Tom. I will implement your suggestions. It looks like rogue paragraph tags were a byproduct of headings created for the icons at the page level, like so "<!-- MCCORMICK -->," "<!-- ADIDAS -->," etc. Is there a way I may be able to replace these headings at the page level? Removing these headings solves the problem, but the information on the page becomes a little less clear. I'm not sure if there is a page level alternative that will allow headings for organizational purposes?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm completely following your question with the headers. The two snippets you showed are both HTML comments. So users would never see those headers (Adidas, McCormick, etc). If you want to keep those HTML comments, I'd suggest trying to remove the comma right after the closing html tag ("-->,") If that comma is actually following your HTML comment, here is where your error might lie.

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I'll just remove the comments and find a better way to structure the content. They were causing the excess space. I'm also curious as to why the image link must be listed 3 times per image?

Comment: At this point, playing around with the code options you have provided above, I'm just having a couple issues with consistent padding or margin space. Any smaller margin I set for the main container seems to be unresponsive. Any smaller padding I set for the images compromises the size of the final "GAP" image. I'm not sure which of your recommendations might be best for this. I may remove the main "row" div entirely, and just style the individual images.